# What workflow should I use for processing RAW photos in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, raw, workflow, image-processing

I started shooting in RAW, and I use Adobe Lightroom.

What workflow would you recommend to use for the processing?
I will really appreciate a detailed description of the steps (or a link to one).

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My workflow is pretty simple, as most of the heavy lifting is done in Photoshop, but Lightroom is often enough for simple shots.

- Download the RAW files into a folder
  of your choice. I typically name them
  YYYYMMDD_NameOfShoot so it's
  relatively organised. For paid
  assignments I will also create
  separate folders for untouched RAW
  files, WIP files, and Finished files.
- Go into the LR Library module and use
  Add Folder to import the files.
- Proof them in the Library module. I
  will only spend time to process files
  that I like, and I junk those that
  are just bad. I use the Rating
  feature, giving one star for those
  that are technically correct ie
  correctly focused, correct DOF, etc.
- Go through the one-star pics one more
  time by using the "Rated" filter, and
  add stars slowly, continuing to
  filter out the pics that do not
  tickle my fancy till I only see pics
  with a 5-star rating.-
- This is where the processing begins
  really. I start with looking at white
  balance, then  clipping highlights
  and shadows, recovering them as
  necessary, and adjusting exposure if
  needed.
- Crop as needed.-
- Then comes colour accuracy. You can
  tweak them using the HSL settings on 
  the right.
- Do some cleaning up via the Dust
  Removal tool.
- Then comes sharpening. I typically
  add a smidgen of Clarity and
  Contrast.
- If the pic needs more work, I edit it
  in Photoshop, then save the edits as 
  a PSD.
- Go back to Lightroom and Export as
  needed.

No one's workflow is exactly the same though, and I would suggest you play around in LR so you can find and refine your own workflow. It takes time, but it will not be wasted as you bring your images to life.

Comment: nothing on file backups? that should be a pretty big deal right!

Answer (score 2):

From what I have seen in videos on YouTube and in reading is that you should start from basics/library section then move to develop to fine tune. Photography boils down to taste.

To be artistic, you have the default in basics/library... lots of black and white and colour tools to use with or without auto tone.

I love Lightroom, and it can make a OK photo pretty special. I have just started using it on the 'try before you buy' program and I am very impressed.

It's recommended that you still use Elements or Photoshop as Lightroom very limited in ways but totally amazing in others.

If you have a noisy photo, or it's a bit off focus and needs sharpening, use the sharpening tool and luminance tool.

The vignette tool is amazing.

If you are doing 100 photos or more that you shot at the same speed and focal length, you can adjust the exposure and contrast in a flash. It's that quick and pain-free. I will be crying when my time usage is up.

Go to YouTube and tap on Lightroom. I personally think you shoul play around and get a feel for the software if you are not on a time limit like me. I have 26 days left on my Lightroom trial :(

When using a photo for the web, it stamps every photo with your name and copyright... you don't have to think about doing it once you have gone to export. Voila, like magic, the photo has your mark on it.

http://www.photoshopsupport.com/lightroom/tutorials.html